# Rocketry : Combine two accelerometers to reduce noise?

Tags: filters, kalman-filters, sensor, integration

I am designing an IMU for an experimental rocket. I'll be using the BN055 9DOF that has sensor fusion - orientation quaternion - and gravity compensation.

My main goal is speed computation, and I was told that using 2 accelerometers in the same time may help reduce the noise (I'll implement a kalman filter to combine data from both accelerometers and integrate).

So my question is : Is that relevant ? And if yes should the 2nd accelerometer be high G (+100G) or low G (16G same as BN055) ?

Thank you in advance for your help